# Query a table as if it had extra (virtual?) rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
| id | fun_data     | value |
|----+--------------+-------|
|  1 | {A1, B1, B2} | foo   |
|  2 | {A1, B1, C1} | bar   |
```

I wish to construct a query using another array which will match all rows of the table according to the following rules:

1. Input array contains at most one code of each category (A/B/C)
2. Query must return rows where there are matching codes for each category

For example:

- input (A1, B1) matches only row 1
- input (A1, B2) matches only row 1
- input (A1, B1, C1) matches rows 1 and 2
- input (A1, C1) matches no rows

I was thinking I should first construct an intermediate table like this:

```
| fun_data     | value |
|--------------+-------|
| {A1, B1}     | foo   |
| {A1, B2}     | foo   |
| {A1, B1, C1} | bar   |
```

And then query it with:

```sql
SELECT value FROM /* intermediate table goes here here */
WHERE fun_data <@ input_data;
```

How can I construct this intermediate table?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks yes that was a my mistake when I wrote the example (corrected it to `1`)

Comment: "input (A1, B1, C1) matches rows 1 and 2
input (A1, C1) matches no rows" why - not "matches only row 2" ?

Comment: Ah, ok now I've got it - "Query must return rows where there are matching codes for each category"

Comment: Your intermediate table wouldn't work for the case `input (A1, B1, C1) matches rows 1 and 2` with the query you give.